# email id change - Uber cart in drupal

Tags: php, drupal, ubercart

how to change the notification email id in uber cart? I mean after checkout process success, admin need to get mail to this email id.

Answer (score 1):

The notification emails are controlled by the Conditional Actions module. Look under **Admin > Store administration > Conditional actions**. Look for the *E-mail admin checkout notification* action and click on its *edit* link. Expand the *Action: Email an order invoice* fieldset and update the Recipients field, as needed.